# Joda time find how many hours less for a complete year

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

If we have an

```
Interval = 2014-09-30T12:11:34.821+01:00 / 2015-09-30T10:11:34.821+01:00
```

which is just 2H less the the full 12M period , so for any given interval , i want to know how many hours its less to complete a year ?

How do I check that programmatically ? that should cover the leap year also

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Joda time [Hours](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Hours.html) utility class. It was specifically created to tackle calculations on hours.

Answer (score 0):

Is this helpful for you?

```
Interval i = Interval.parse("2014-09-30T12:11:34.821+01:00/2015-09-30T10:11:34.821+01:00");
int delta = Hours.hoursBetween(i.getEnd(), i.getStart().plusYears(1)).getHours();
System.out.println("hour-delta=" + delta); // output: hour-delta=2
```